# Spring boot javabean that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired

I have POJO classes which are for 90% accessed using services and repositories, but in those 10% cases I want a service to have a attribute of a POJO and in those cases the autowiring fails.

At runtime I get "Parameter 0 of constructor in com.ripple.trading.impl.Trader required a bean of type 'com.ripple.repositories.pojo.Wallet' that could not be found." This is the Trader class:

```
  @Service
public class Trader implements ITrade {
    private Wallet wallet;
    private List<Quantity> balance;
    private Advice latestAdvice;


@Autowired
private OrderService orderService;
@Autowired
private HistoryService historyService;
@Autowired
private CurrencyService currencyService;

private Advice lastAdvice;

public Trader(Wallet wallet, Advice advice){
    this.lastAdvice = Advice.HOLD;
    this.wallet = wallet;
    this.balance = WalletFetcher.getWalletByAddress(this.wallet.getAddress());
    this.latestAdvice = advice;
}
}
```

This is the wallet

```
@Document
public class Wallet extends BaseModel implements Serializable{

private String address;
private String encryptedSecret;
private String name;


/**
 * Instantiates a new Wallet.
 *
 * @param address         the address
 * @param encryptedSecret the encrypted secret
 */
@PersistenceConstructor
public Wallet(String address, String encryptedSecret, String name) {
    this.address = address;
    this.encryptedSecret = encryptedSecret;
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Gets address.
 *
 * @return the address
 */
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

/**
 * Sets address.
 *
 * @param address the address
 */
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Gets encrypted secret.
 *
 * @return the encrypted secret
 */
public String getEncryptedSecret() {
    return encryptedSecret;
}

/**
 * Sets encrypted secret.
 *
 * @param encryptedSecret the encrypted secret
 */
public void setEncryptedSecret(String encryptedSecret) {
    this.encryptedSecret = encryptedSecret;
}
}
```

And this is my main application

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@ComponentScan
@EnableMongoRepositories(value = "com.ripple.repositories.mongo")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class RippleSpringApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(RippleSpringApplication.class);
}

/**
 * The entry point of application.
 *
 * @param args the input arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RippleSpringApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

My guess is the autowiring, maybe break the application down in smaller pieces until it works again. It's an issue that previously had occurred and refactoring fixed it, but the reason behind it, why did it fixed it, was it the right solution. That's what I'm after now.

My applicationclass is in the root package so ComponentScan shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `Wallet` is not a Spring configured bean. It's just a class (a spring-data-mongodb `document`).

If your Spring component has a single constructor, Spring automatically considers this constructor for autowiring and will look for beans matching the constructor argument types to provide when calling that constructor.

That is why you're receiving that error.

If you want `Trader` to be a "service" consider not making `Wallet` and `Advice` it's fields because that essentially introduces state into what should be stateless. If you have methods in `Trader` that do something with the `Wallet` and `Advice` consider passing those as parameters to those methods. Something like:

```
@Service
public class Trader {
  /// ... your autowired dependecies

  public BigDecimal getBalance(Wallet wallet) { 
    return WalletFetcher.getWalletByAddress(wallet.getAddress()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this because @Service makes it a singleton and singleton can't hold a state? Thanks for the advice, now I know the details why it's done this way. `@Override
    public void trade(Wallet wallet, Advice advice) {
        JSONObject order = null;

        Currency base = null;
        Currency counter = null;

        this.balance = WalletFetcher.getWalletByAddress(wallet.getAddress());}` This indeed takes a "state" out of class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `wallet` class is not managed by Spring, it's not `@Component` that enables to be picked up via Component Scanning, it's not defined as a `@Bean` in your configuration.

Additionally the Wallet class is stateful, and realistically you should not be having spring manage this class but passing it as a parameter to required Beans.

Comment: The Spring Data mongodb reference documentation says that @Docment is just a custom implementation of @Entity or is this just not the same. In the constructor I pass it as a parameter and then `this.wallet = wallet;`

Comment: an `@Entitiy` is not the concept as a Spring Managed Bean.

Comment: Ooh it's a JPA annotation and doesn't seem to be necessary even